# Uniform kernel function returning NaN

Tags: r, function, kernel, nan

I'm writing my own uniform kernel function like so:

```
uniform.kernel <- function(data, predict.at, iv.name, dv.name, bandwidth){
  #Load in the DV/IV and turn them into vectors
  iv <- data$iv.name
  dv <- data$dv.name

  #Given the point we're predicting,
  #what kernel weights does each observation of the iv receive?
  kernelvalue <- ifelse(abs((iv - predict.at)/bandwidth)<= 1, 0.5,0)

  #Given these kernel values and the dv,
  #what is our estimate of the conditional expectation?
  conditional.expectation <-sum(kernelvalue*dv)/sum(kernelvalue)

  #Return the expectation
  return(conditional.expectation)
}
```

And then applying it to this data:

```
set.seed(101)
x <- seq(from=0, to=100, by=.1)
errors <- runif(min=.5, max=5000, n=length(x))
y <- x^2 - 3*x + errors^1.1
combo.frame <- cbind.data.frame(x,y)
```

Only, when I apply the function to the data (like below), I get "NaN".

```
uniform.kernel(combo.frame, 20, "x","y", 4)
```

However, when I just write out the steps within my function to the data set directly (without using the function), I get the correct answer. For example, I do the following and get the correct results:

```
kernelvalue <- ifelse(abs((combo.frame$x - 20)/4)<= 1, 0.5,0)
conditional.expectation <- sum(kernelvalue*combo.frame$y)/sum(kernelvalue)
```

Why am I getting NaN when I use the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the `$` operator with `character` objects like that. Use the `[` operator instead. Replace the first two lines in your function like this:

```
  iv <- data[,iv.name]
  dv <- data[,dv.name]
```

and it works as expected.

Comment: If you like the answer, you can click the check mark to the left of the question.